# How to place a java array in a scope variable?

Tags: java, xpages

I would like to place a Java array in a scope variable. Here is how the array is build

```
Person[] persons = null;
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(url);
String json = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
persons = mapper.readValue(json, Person[].class);
return persons
```

I use the Jackson library to parse JSON into Java objects ref: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html

I can bind the persons array directly to a repeat control.

However if I attempt to store the array first in a scope variable I get a 500 error message.

```
var persons = personsBeanTest.getPersons("http://dev1/fakenames.nsf/api/data/collections/name/people?count=10");
viewScope.put("names",persons);
```

HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in C:/Program Files/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
HTTP JVM: CLFAD0229E: Security exception occurred servicing request for: /fakenames.nsf/index_1.xsp - HTTP Code: 500. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in C:/Program Files/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how I should correct the code to place the array into a scope variable?

Comment: Did you do as the message sais and consulted the log file? The exception also contains `Security exception occurred` so I'd look in that direction.

Comment: things solve when u include serializable ...

Answer (score 2):

Good point from Thomas in the comment: when using an external lib like Jackson you have to set permissions for it in the Java security policy settings. How to do that is explained here http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=EAA or here http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/java-security-in-ibm-domino/

Answer (score 2):

I had to include serializable for my objects :-/

Comment: I typically include Serializable for every object I create.  Whether it really needs it or not.  I don't know of any reason not to implement it.

Comment: David, some Java gurus might say that implementing Serializable has an impact on performance. I personally use it only when the runtime tells me to do that and of course in the class that is used as a bean via faces-config.xml.

Comment: In a non-XPages environment, it's wise to use Serializable judiciously for a number of reasons, but with XPages-side stuff, I'm pretty carefree about it. I don't think just implementing it affects performance - the potential gotchas are more about third-party use and long-term maintainability of stored objects, but that's not generally an issue here.